# mysql, time since last login listing

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a table with ID (auto inc) and DATETIME.

I have been sending the date/time to mysql with $thedate=date("Y-m-d-h-m-s");

Now I need to find all customers who have not placed an order for 4 days say.  What is the best way to do this?

Should I have used a different column type to store the information?  This "listing all customers who have not ordered in last 4 days" is the only thing it is used for.

Comment: Your `date()` is using month where you want minutes `date('Y-m-d-H-i-s)` I would also use `H` for 24h clock

Comment: I had not seen this! thanks!! wow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OMG**... `$thedate=date("Y-m-d-h-m-s")` is wrongly formatted

should be `$thedate=date("Y-m-d-H-i-s")`

to get customer who has not place an order in last 4 days

```
select 
  user_id, max(order_date) as last_order_date
from 
  your_table
group by user_id
having last_order_date<date_sub(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, interval 4 day);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Y-m-d H-i-s"? (Presume MySQL copes either way.)

Comment: In this case, please include your table schema for both tables (customer table, and your table for transaction/order)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```